# Implementing Collaborative Authentication in Java Web Application

Tags: java, authentication, web-applications

I've a requirement to build a Java based web application where a resource should be available only when all the authorized users of that resource are logged in. Also, if any authorized user logs out, the resource should no longer be available to any of them.

The resource could be of any type(html pages, pdf documents, spread sheets etc.,)

Is there any existing authentication standards/protocols that supports this type of requirement or I've to build this from scratch?

Comment: Are you already using any specific web framework ?

Comment: I am comfortable with Spring framework. I am also ready to switch to any other framework if it supports this requirement.

Answer (score 4):

> the resource should be available only when all the authorized users of that resource are logged in. Also, if any authorized user logs out, the resource should no longer be available to any of them.

Once you have given access to the resource to an user, this user will be able to download / take screenshots / save / record the resource, no matter if it's a PDF document, an image, an audio file. I don't know the context and the goal of what you're trying to build, but you should know that it will be insecure in any case.

Even putting this consideration aside, you'll need a real-time solution. Once the user has loaded the page containing the resource, you need to be able to hide or deny modification rights to him. This means you have to use something like WebSockets or Ajax Polling on the client side to have the frontend know when your server considers that not all the required users are online, and that the access to the resource should be "denied". But once more since this is client-side code it can easily be changed or altered, the requests it is sending can easily be blocked by the user, so it is once again **inherently insecure**.

I'd suggest giving a little bit of context here and describing what is the problem you're trying to solve, because most likely there's a more reasonable solution to solve it.

If what you need to do is to deny *modification rights* if not all the "resource owners" are online, it is more easily doable since the modifications will happen on the server side. In this case, a solution using WebSockets could quite easily be implemented but I don't know a library or framework that does such a thing. Most likely you will have to build it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me and I've accomplished my requirement. Unfortunately, I could not post my solution for some reasons.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you consider that my answer solved your problem, please accept it - otherwise the bounty you put on the question will be lost.

Comment: Am sorry. The below post also helped me. Am in a confusion whether to accept yours or the one below.

Comment: I can understand the struggle! Just choose one of the two in the next 19 hours, otherwise you will have lost 500 of reputation for nothing. :-/

Comment: I wish that the answer be auto selected and bounty awarded accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not constrained to use a specific web framework, feel free to try the following filter based implementation for jersey. Note that you still need to add a fair amount of custom code for handling the logic of "Collective authentication" as jersey only provides the basic tools required for this, and it doesn't explicitly implement the whole concept. Here's how you could do it, on a high level:

```
class AuthorizationProvider {

    public void authenticate(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        // Here you would need to query your database to get the Collection of Users belonging 
        // to the "Collective" Role. You would then check if they are all logged in.
        // A really abstract version would look like this, assuming you've already queried the DB
        // and have a reference to the above mentioned Collection.

        if (collectiveUsers.size == collectiveUsers.stream().filter(User::isLoggedIn).count()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class AuthorizationRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final AuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        if (authorizationProvider.authenticate(requestContext)) {
            // serve whatever it is you want to serve if all required users are logged in
        } else {
            // otherwise reject the request
            requestContext.abortWith(Response
                .status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                .entity("Resource available only after collective login")
                .build());
        }
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("/")
class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        // Register the filter
        register(AuthorizationRequestFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Apart from this, you would also need to handle the Login part.
You would assign these specific users the Collective role, and you would mark them as logged in, whenever they successfully pass through login authentication.

If all the above conditions are met, you should be able to successfully serve your "Collective only" page, only when all "Collective" users are logged in.

This also covers the part where if either one of these users logs out, you store the state in your database (mark the Collective user with isLoggedIn = false). So from this point on, whenever somebody requests the page, it will return Unauthorized.

Conversely, you can also attempt to implement SSE (Server sent events) to actively update the frontend part, if somebody logs out. With this, the page will actively be disabled even if somebody has already managed to get it previously.

Container request filter source and example, for reference, [jersey docs](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me and I've accomplished my requirement. Unfortunately, I could not post my solution for some reasons.

Comment: Glad it helped ! Although it might be a bit late, feel free to mark this one or the one above as accepted. Cheers !

Comment: I wish that the answer be auto selected and bounty awarded accordingly.